# converting classic vb to vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

what is the vb.net equivalent or similar of recordset.underlyingvalue and recordset.value in vb?

I'm converting a vb application to vb.net and i've replaced the recordsets with datasets but i have not been able to figure this out. any help would be really appreciated.

i've tried making a copy of the dataset and comparing values to track the changes but that doesn't seem very efficient. Here is a piece of code that i'm trying to convert.

```
For Each fld In rs.Fields
        bfldChanged = False
        Select Case fld.Type
            Case adDate, adDBDate, adDBTime, adDBTimeStamp:                    
                If IsDate(fld.UnderlyingValue) And Not IsDate(fld.Value) Then
                    bfldChanged = True
                ElseIf Not IsDate(fld.UnderlyingValue) And IsDate(fld.Value) Then
                    bfldChanged = True
                ElseIf IsDate(fld.UnderlyingValue) And IsDate(fld.Value) Then
                    If fld.UnderlyingValue <> fld.Value Then
                        bfldChanged = True
                    Else
                        bfldChanged = False
                    End If
                Else
                    bfldChanged = False
                End If
            Case Else:
                If (fld.UnderlyingValue <> fld.Value) Then
                    bfldChanged = True
                Else
                    bfldChanged = False
                End If
        End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent to that particular property.  Data Access in .NET is very different than Data Access in VB6 and prior.  The DataTable is only ***marginally*** like a RecordSet.

However, looking at the code, it looks like you're just checking to see if the table contains changes.  You can use the [DataTable.GetChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649.aspx) method to determine this a lot more simply.

---

*Not part of the official answer, but a general recommendation.*

I've converted tons of VB6 apps to .NET apps, and experience has taught me that doing a line-by-line conversion attempt is almost always a bad idea.  The two are quite different, and in every case, it's proved to be more efficient and eror-free to just start over from scratch.  Make sure I understand what the VB6 app did (requirementes) map it all out, flowchart everything, and then build the .NET version from scratch.  I've had nothing but headaches doing it any other way.

Comment: Going through that very process often illustrates how much of COM et al was buried under the hood of VB6, which often prevented you from really gaining some of the nice benefits of VB.NET in the transition, too.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I did a small testing on datatable.getchanges() and it seems to be exactly what i needed. I agree with both of you that it is always better to start fresh instead of attempting a line by line conversion. i'm just starting out with .NET and the pressure of the project deadline seems to have led me into bad programming practices. but i'm going to try to get better at this. it just makes so much sense. thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped.  Good luck!  Welcome to .NET, too.  It's actually not that much of a learning curve, once you get past the differences in data access.

Comment: just stumbled upon this datarow("Column Name/Index",DataRowVersion.Original) .. could i use this for the above scenario?